# Add Line Item to "My Order" block

Tags: hooks, ubercart

I am using Drupal 7 Ubercart 3. Though I have added line item "Gift Wrapping" successfully using a module, I want to show it as well in the order "My Order" block so that the user immediately sees the fee in the order instead of seeing it on the review page. Please tell me is it possible to show line item in the cart along with other products?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here. 
This may help you.  `hook_line_item`

http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_line_item

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function uc_order_line_item() {
  $items[] = array(
    'id' => 'generic',
    'title' => t('Empty Line'),
    'weight' => 2,
    'default' => FALSE,
    'stored' => TRUE,
    'add_list' => TRUE,
    'calculated' => TRUE,
    'callback' => 'uc_line_item_generic',
  );
  return
$items;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please add some steps, how to use this code for this issue.